# AnyLogic: How to get the average, CI for a Queue

Tags: java, statistics, queue, anylogic

My problem is that I have 4 Queues. The agents are created in a Source and move to a Queue, then they wait until some condition is true to move to the delay.

I want to get the average, confidence interval, min, max, etc.. of the waiting time in the Queue as well as the delay time for the agents.

What I did is the following:

I linked timeMeasureStart with the Queue and linked timeMeasureEnd with the delay before the Sink.

Then I dragged histogram data to the main. in the Value I wrote: 
max (timeMeasureEnd) in order to get the max value of it.

it says: Description: The method max(int, int) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (TimeMeasureEnd).

Comment: can you put the code you have tried in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF.

Do use the statistics object and learn how to use it. The standard "[Bank office](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ELT%2FBank%20Model.html&cp=1_3_0)" tutorial shows you how to do just that.

Strongly suggest you also do all the other step-by-step tutorials, they are extremely helpful ;-)

PS: On SOF, you typically try to show your previous work. Statements like "I tried but it didn't work" are not helpful. Check out this [guide to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :-)

Comment: I am sorry for not showing my previous work.. What I did is that I followed the instructions in Statistics, I typed confidence interval in Value bar but it doesn`t appeear. I can`t get the confidence interval

Comment: Again, this is very unclear. Really not sure what you mean :-) Do edit your question and add specific details of the problem, what you already tried, screenshots... Make life as easy as possible for us ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Then I dragged histogram data to the main. in the Value I wrote: max (timeMeasureEnd) in order to get the max value of it.
>
> it says: Description: The method max(int, int) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (TimeMeasureEnd).

Please learn about code-complete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) and how to understand what functions are doing. The `max` function compares 2 given ints and returns the larger one. Irrelevant for what you want.

Again, study the "Bank office" tutorial and learn how they pull queue statistics there. No need to go beyond that for your needs.

PS: "confidence interval" is not something you get from your data. You likely mean st-dev, right?